# The sum of all numbers between 1 and 1000 (inclusive) that are divisible by 3 or 5, but not both

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I found a problem that asked to calculate the sums of all numbers between $1$ and $1000$ (inclusive) that are divisible by $3$ or $5$, but not both.

I immediately thought of Gauss which made me smile but didn't get me anywhere. I thought of using the summation, but I still have no idea how to do this but by brute force. Any ideas?

I'll likely need fairly explicit explanations. I'm an undergrad who has just learned basic proving techniques and is just starting to apply it to abstract algebra, analysis, etc.

Comment: Try doing the sum over $3n$, and also over $5n$, then subtracting the sum over $15n$...

Comment: I kind of see the logic of what you're saying, but you're gonna have to give me a lot more than that for me to understand how to calculate that.

Comment: Any time a person posts here asking for an explicit answer, it inspires suspicion. If you are interested in learning, a complete answer is no help. If a person is not interested in learning, they are posting here for reasons that are independent of learning. If you want an explicit answer, Google "Project Euler Problem 1"

Comment: @abiessu:  We need to subtract **twice** the sum of the multiples of $15$.

Comment: I got mistaken again... It's 3(1+2+...+333)+5(1+2+...+200)-2*15(1+2+...+66).

Comment: Thomas, I see your point. I don't mean to inspire suspicion. I have seen several answers on this site which are explicit and show all necessary steps, so I didn't feel that's improper etiquette on this site although perhaps I'm wrong; I've only had an account here for a month or so. I've also noticed that often times, people will give me partial/vague ideas which might help me on some level but not enough to reach an answer because they often seem to assume I'm familiar with many things that I'm not as an undergrad, so I felt that it might be a smart idea to ask for a more explicit answer.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: true, I was giving major hints, but not concerning myself with details such as sum coefficients...

Comment: This makes sense to me except why do we have to multiply by the 15 sequence by 2?

Answer (score 2):

I have a proposal for the solution of the more general problem for the sum of like powers of arbitrary natural exponents. This is based on the Faulhaber-/Bernoulli-polynomials.
Consider that polynomials organized in a matrix (which I called "Gp" when I found them). Each row *r* contain the coefficients for the *r* 'th Faulhaber polynomial. I introduce also the notation for a "Vandermondevector" -type: $ V(x) = \text{columnvector}(1,x,x^2,x^3,...)$; if I use it as diagonalmatrix I prefix it with a "d" like $\ ^dV(x)$.
The matrix $Gp$ begins like
$$ \Tiny  \begin{bmatrix} 
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 0 & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 0 & 1/6 & 1/2 & 1/3 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 0 & 0 & 1/4 & 1/2 & 1/4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 0 & -1/30 & 0 & 1/3 & 1/2 & 1/5 & 0 \\ 
 0 & 0 & -1/12 & 0 & 5/12 & 1/2 & 1/6
 \end{bmatrix}$$
and along the rows we see the coefficients for the ***integrals*** of the Bernoulli-polynomials. 
Using that in a matrix-formula we get
$$ Gp \cdot V(m) = V(1) + V(2) + V(3) + ... + V(m) $$
To have the sum $V(3)+V(6)+...+V(3m)$ instead it suffices to write
$$ ( ^dV(3) \cdot Gp \cdot \  ^dV(1/3))\cdot V(3m) = V(3) + V(6) + V(9) + ... + V(3m) $$
Thus, introducing a matrix-valued-function $$H(x) \overset{\text{def}}= \ ^dV(x) \cdot Gp \cdot \  ^dV(1/x) $$
allows to write
$$ \begin{eqnarray} H(3) \cdot V(3m) &=& V(3)+V(6)+...+V(15)+ ... +V(3m) \\ 
   H(5) \cdot V(5m) &=& V(5)+V(10)+...V(15) + ... +V(5m) \\
   H(15) \cdot V(15m) &=& V(15)+V(30)+... +V(15m) \\
 \end{eqnarray}
 $$
and finally, with a notation for the highest integer equal or below *n* divisible by *m* for convenience 
$$ n:m \overset{\text{def}}{=} m \cdot \Big\lfloor  { n \over m} \Big\rfloor $$ we can write
$$ S_{3,5}(m) = H(3)\cdot V( m:3) + H(5) \cdot V(m:5) - 2H(15) \cdot V(m:15 ) $$
For $m=1000$ we get the vector of solutions for the sums with exponents *0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7* 
$$ \begin{matrix} S_{3,5}(1000) &=& \small \begin{bmatrix}\begin{array} {rll}
 401 &\Tiny = 3^0+6^0+...+999^0 + 5^0+10^0+...+1000^0 -2(15^0+30^0+...+990^0)\\ 
 201003 &\Tiny = 3+6+...+999 + 5+10+15+...+1000 -2(15+30+...+990)\\ 
 134335661 &\Tiny = 3^2+6^2+...+999^2 + 5^2+10^2+...+1000^2 -2(15^2+30^20+...+990^2)\\ 
 101003482917 \\ 
 81004632555017 \\ 
 67672443055260693 \\ 
 58149771588796814081 \\ 
 51008046700741091931597
 \end{array} \end{bmatrix} \end{matrix}$$
The formulae are
$$ \begin{matrix} S_{3,5}&=& \small \begin{bmatrix} \begin{array} {l}
 \frac 13 m_3+\frac 15 m_5- \frac 2{15} m_{15} \\ 
 \frac     1  6  m_3^2   +\frac 12 m_3
   + \frac 1{10} m_5^2   +\frac 12 m_5
   - \frac 1{15} m_{15}^2-  m_{15} \\ 
 \frac 1 9 m_3^3+ \frac 12 m_3^2+\frac 12 m_3
+\frac 1{15}m_5^3+\frac 12 m_5^2+ \frac 56m_5
-\frac 2{45} m_{15}^3-m_{15}^2-5 m_{15} \\ \vdots \end{array}
 \end{bmatrix} \end{matrix}$$
where the $m_k$ denote the  $(m:k) = k \cdot \lfloor \frac mk \rfloor$.

You're interested in the second row $S_{3,5;1}$.
With $m=1000 $ inserted you get
$$\small 
 \frac 16 m_3^2+\frac 12 m_3+ \frac 1{10}m_5^2+\frac 12 m_5-\frac 1{15} m_{15}^2-m_{15} 
$$
and with $m_3=999,m_5=1000,m_{15}=990$ inserted you get
$$ S_{3,5;1}(1000) = \frac 12(\frac 1 3  999^2+  999
                    + \frac 1 5 1000^2+ 1000
                    -\frac 2{15} 990^2-2 \cdot 990) $$
which is finally
$$ S_{3,5;1}(1000) = 201003 $$

One can arrive at the last formula for the second row by far simpler means (as shown in other answers); however for the general problem: to get the rows for the sums-of-like-powers with higher exponents, I think this (known) array of Faulhaber-polynomials (handled by the matrix-formulae) should be the general and most convenient one.

---

*(as someone remarked already: this (without the removal of the multiples of 15) is also the "project-euler-problem-1", but much generalized)*

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) for this one.  If you know how to sum the numbers 1 through $n$ then you can deduce a formula for the sum of $k$, $2k$, $\dots$, $nk$ and tie everything together with inclusion-exclusion.

Answer (score 0):

I think folks coming along later might appreciate a simple approach using programming approach and it's based off of the Gauss approach!

```
from math import ceil, floor

def sum_divisible_range(rangeLow, rangeHigh, divisor):

        lowMultiple = ceil(rangeLow / divisor) - 1
        highMultiple = floor(rangeHigh / divisor)

        sequenceSum = (highMultiple ** 2 + highMultiple) // 2 - (lowMultiple ** 2 + lowMultiple) // 2

        return divisor * sequenceSum

print(sum_divisible_range(0, 1000, 3) + sum_divisible_range(0, 1000, 5) - 2 * sum_divisible_range(0, 1000, 15))
```

So, one can start by noticing that what we want to do is we want to sum up the numbers divisible by 3 and the numbers divisible by 5 and then remove the numbers divisible by 15.

So, what we really want is an efficient way to find the sum of the numbers divisible by 3 and by 5 and by 15 and then we can do the following:

```
sum_three_multiples + sum_five_multiples - 2 * sum_fifteen_multiples
```

We subtract the sum_fifteens twice because they are going to appear once in the sum_three_multiples (e.g. ..., 9, 12, 15, 18, ...) and once in the sum_five_multiples (e.g. 5, 15, 20, ...).

So, something we notice about the sum of the multiples of some number between a range is that there is a lower multiple and a higher multiple.

```
3 * (n) + 3 * (n + 1) ... + 3 * (k - 1) + 3 * (k)
```

We can then reorganize these in the following way:

```
3 * (n + (n + 1) + ... + k)
```

Then we can use the arithmetic sum formula based on combinations to clean this up.

```
3 * (C(k+1,2) - C(n,2))
```

And, we have our efficient way to find the sum of numbers divisible by some number within a range!